# AWS Amplify send an email after graphql mutation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify

I need to send an email after a mutation. My graphql schema saves to the database using the @model directive but I want to add to it and send an email after the mutation. Can someone please recommend the best way to do this? Below is my graphql schema.

```
enum Service {
  AIRPORT_PICKUP
  AIRPORT_DROPOFF
  GUIDED_TOUR
  DRIVER
}

type Message
@model
@auth(
  rules: [
    { allow: public, provider: iam, operations: [create] }
    { allow: groups, groups: ["admin"], operations: [update, delete, read] }
  ]
) {
  id: ID!
  firstName: String!
  lastName: String!
  email: AWSEmail!
  phoneCountryCode: String
  phoneNumber: String
  message: String!
  arrivalFlightNumber: String
  arrivalDateTime: AWSDateTime
  departurelFlightNumber: String
  departureDateTime: AWSDateTime
  travelers: Int
  services: [Service]
  owner: String
  group: String
}
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I am facing the same issue. One option would be to create a lamda function (amplify add function) with an endpoint to call. But I would rather like to have it as close to the creation/mutation as possible. Another option would be the create a  DynamoDB trigger, that calls a lambda function. I had that, but unfortunately I experienced that it is not that reliable, does not always trigger. Anyhow, let me know if you found a nice solution.

Comment: I'm also look for an example of how to use email from aws amplify? I suspect as well that I need to setup a function and call that, but don't really know where to start.

Comment: Doing some searching I found this, which shows how to call a lambda function using the amplify graphql stuff. I think when I find an email lambda function, I can call it this way.  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/amplify-framework-adds-support-for-aws-lambda-functions-and-amazon-dynamodb-custom-indexes-in-graphql-schemas/